# how to run rdesktop command from php in linux?

Tags: linux, php, rdesktop, xrdp

I want to open `rdesktop` `xrdp` window by just clicking on button from [php](/questions/tagged/php) website in [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) machine.

Here is the php code :

```
shell_exec('rdesktop localhost');
```

This will not display any error.

Comment: You want the web server to run the remote desktop client?!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to the [exec()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. I think this is what you are looking for.